# Insensitive keys with the same value in a searching program

Tags: python, dictionary, case-sensitive

I would like to examine a text containing a word somewhere and the same word with the first letter uppercase at the beginning of a sentence. Then I want to be able to label both the same in a dictionary making use of a command in a searching program.

For example, having a text containing 'the' and 'The' I would like to compose a dictionary that recognizes both as 'DETERMINER' without having to define every single word as 'DETERMINER' tediously:

```
dict['the']='DETERMINER'
dict['The]='DETERMINER'
```

etc.

Comment: What if tiger and Tiger don't have the same value in `dic`?

Comment: e.g. `dic = {'tiger':'animal','Tiger':'rock','rose':'plant'}`, or can this not happen in your case?

Comment: It is enough to write dict['[Tt]he']='DETERMINER.'

Comment: Taken from page 15 of SPEECH AND LANGUAGE PROCESSING (3rd ed.). Jurafsky, Daniel ; Martin, James H. ; Editorial: PEARSON EDUCATION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be a beginner, I will propose you a more verbose code:

```
dic = {'tiger':'animal','Tiger':'animal','rose':'plant'}
result = {}
for key in dic:
    dic[key.lower()] = dic[key] # the key is always in lower case. If it exists already, it will be overriden.
print(result)
```

This should help you with getting started. You could check for different values for the same lowercase key and throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options where you have duplicate keys.

#### Take the last value by insertion order

In Python 3.7+ (or CPython 3.6 as an implementation detail), you can take the last value by *insertion order*. In other cases, order should not be assumed.

```
dic = {'tiger': 'animal', 'Tiger': 'animal2', 'rose': 'plant'}  # example input
newdic = {k.casefold(): v for k, v in dic.items()}

{'rose': 'plant', 'tiger': 'animal2'}
```

#### Prefer either lowercase or capitalized value

For lowercase:

```
newdic = {k.casefold(): dic.get(k.casefold(), v) for k, v in dic.items()}

{'rose': 'plant', 'tiger': 'animal'}
```

Similarly, for uppercase:

```
newdic = {k.capitalize(): dic.get(k.capitalize(), v) for k, v in dic.items()}

{'Rose': 'plant', 'Tiger': 'animal2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
dic = {'tiger':'animal','Tiger':'animal','rose':'plant'}
result = { key.lower() : value for key, value in dic.items() }
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'tiger': 'animal', 'rose': 'plant'}
```